# CMake unable to find my Windows installation of wxWidgets

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake, wxwidgets

I've tried to link wxWidgets 3.0.2 to my C++ project but CMake can't seem to find it.

The wxWidgets that I'm trying to get CMake to find is from [wxMSW-Setup-3.0.2.exe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/3.0.2/wxMSW-Setup-3.0.2.exe)

This is the error it gives me:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 12 2013
CMake Error at D:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
    Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    D:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
    D:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:871 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
    CMakeLists.txt:66 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

`CMakeLists.txt:66` refers to this line:

```
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED core base)
```

I've tried changing the CMake generator, and running `set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "C:/wxWidgets-3.0.2")`, both of which didn't fix the problem.

CMake is version 3.3.1.

Comment: Try `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:/wxWidgets-3.0.2"`. Accordint to [the documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) it specifies `path used for searching by FIND_XXX()...`.

Comment: @Gluttton it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Try going deeper into `C:/wxWidgets-3.0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think cmake used environement variable to find wxwidgets. You have to set wxDir or wxWin variable to C:/wxWidgets-3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)` instead of `find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS core base)`. And when you build the wxWidgets [https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW)_with_MinGW, use build the static libraries instead of dynamic libraries, I fixed it by using these two steps.