# Windows vs code wxWidgets's #include <wx/wx.h> not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, wxwidgets

I use window10 and vs code to compile some source code.
I can compile the code but when I run the .exe file. Nothing shows up.
I got this error.
[image]

My cmakefile is as follows:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.3)
    
    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
    
    project(membot)
    set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "C:/wxWidgets-3.1.4")
    set(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR "C:/wxWidgets-3.1.4/lib/gcc_dll"
        CACHE PATH "wxWidgets_LIB_DIR ")
    find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS core base)
    include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
    
    file(GLOB project_SRCS src/*.cpp)
    
    add_executable(membot ${project_SRCS})
    target_link_libraries(membot ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
    target_include_directories(membot PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I don't know how to solve it. I also tried to include the path in the c_cpp_properties.json, but still doesn't work.

Comment: try to use `\` instead of `/` in the path. You are on Windows.

Comment: @Igor: Inside a CMake script all paths use forward slash (``/``) as a path separator.

Comment: @ZhiqiangYang: You set a WxWidgets root dir to `C:/wxWidgets-3.1.4`. Check that you have `include/wx/wx.h` file under this directory. (That is, absolute path to the file is `C:/wxWidgets-3.1.4/include/wx/wx.h`.)

Comment: BTW, the error message `wx/wx.h: Not such file or directory` is a **compiler error**. This contradicts to your description "I **can compile** the code but when I run the .exe file. Nothing shows up. I got this error." Please, elaborate when you get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution.

1. In the cmakefile.txt, I use `find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)` instead of  `find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS core base)`

My final cmakefile.txt is like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11.3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

project(membot)

set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "C:/wxWidgets-3.1.4")
set(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR "C:/wxWidgets-3.1.4/lib/gcc_dll")
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED gl core base OPTIONAL_COMPONENTS net)

include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})

file(GLOB project_SRCS src/*.cpp)

add_executable(membot ${project_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(membot ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(membot PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

2. Referring to this https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW
   to have a correct wxwidgets build. I use `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release clean` to clean the dynamic libraries and use `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=0 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release clean` to clean the static libraries. Then I use this  `mingw32-make -j8 -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=0 UNICODE=1 VENDOR=custom` to build static libraries.
3. Use `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..` and `make` to compile the source code. It succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I search a lot for how to solve the problem of:

> Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)

But didn't fix it until I saw [Youshikyou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66834841/8415089)'s answer above

This sentence really solved my problem:

`set(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR "C:/wxWidgets-3.1.4/lib/gcc_dll")`

For anybody who is searching for this problem, hope this will help